# Scroll to element from bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website for a small association. It is built using bootstrap 4, and I have a `navbar` that links to several `flex-container`. I would like these links to scroll smoothly to these elements.

I am using the following jQuery to achieve this:

```
// Scroll to id from nav items
$(".navbar a").click(function () {
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).data('value')).offset().top - $('.navbar').height() - 10
    }, 1000)

});
```

This should scroll to a position corresponding to the top of the `flex-container` `-` the height of the `navbar` `-` a buffer of 10.

I also have the flowing in the the same `.js` file, which uses the [ScrollReveal package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollreveal) to fade in text/images as the user scrolls through:

```
// Reveal text on scroll through
window.sr = ScrollReveal({ reset: true });
sr.reveal('.reveal', { opacity: 0.1, duration:600 });
```

Often clicking a `nav-link` will initially over-scroll, but will re-scroll to the correct position on a second click. I have found that if I remove the `ScrollReveal` call, the scrolling works as expected.

Is there something wrong with either of the above snippets?

```js
// Get height of screen for header
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.header').height($(window).height());
});

// Scroll to id from nav items
$(".navbar a").click(function () {
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).data('value')).offset().top - $('.navbar').height() - 10
    }, 1000)

});

// Header button -> scroll down
$(".header button").click(function () {
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).data('value')).offset().top - $('.navbar').height() - 10
    }, 1000)

});

// This is causing the problem //

// Reveal text on scroll through
window.sr = ScrollReveal({ reset: true });
sr.reveal('.reveal', { opacity: 0.1, duration:600 });
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ISg.ttf) format('truetype');
}

html,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
a {
    font-family: "Raleway", serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

html {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.flex-container {
    padding-left: .8em !important;
    padding-right: .8em !important;
}

/* Nav bar */
.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(26, 62, 85, 0.88);
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(141, 162, 180, 0.9);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link {
    margin-right: 1em !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #4bb2f9 !important;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="description" content="Actin Art homepage"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Nick Riddiford">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<!--Scroll spy-->
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50" class="post">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar fixed-top">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="index.html">
        <img src="images/UK_flag.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="index_fr.html">
        <img src="images/FR_flag.png" alt="">
    </a>

    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navbar links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-value="about" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-value="school-workshops" href="#school-workshops">School Workshops</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-value="books" href="#books">Books</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-value="exhibitions" href="#exhibitions">Exhibitions</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn" href="mailto:asso.actin@gmail.com">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="flex-container mt-5 reveal" id="about">
    <h1 class="text-center display-3 mb-3">About</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <p>Actin Art - <strong>L’association des Artistes et des Scientifiques Actine</strong> - is a science
                communication project that combines science and art. It aims to raise general public interest in the
                sciences and explain recent scientific discoveries. We are creating a series of short, illustrated,
                science-based books that accurately relay science via fun, adventure stories for 3-5 year olds.</p>


            <p class="reveal">As the science is accurate, the parents and teachers reading the stories to the children
                will learn too, and be better able to explain the science to the children. The characters in our stories
                are based on the real molecules, proteins and cells that scientists study in the lab. Our aim is that these books will inspire
                children and adults to become as excited as we are by cells, molecules and biology in general!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <p>
            </p>
            <img src="images/ActinArt_s2.jpg" alt="Actin Art" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container mt-5 reveal" id="school-workshops">
    <h1 class="text-center display-3 mb-3">School workshops</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <img src="images/cadherine-Joann.jpg" alt="Workshop" class="img-fluid">
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <p>We recently held a workshop at the Lyonnais nursery located in the 5th arrondissement in Paris. After
                around 15 minutes of storytelling with our artwork, we held activities that related to some of our
                stories. This was a huge success, and the children were really engaged with our stories. After
                following-up with the school three months later we were delighted to discover that the children
                remembered some of the key concepts from our stories!</p>

            <p class="reveal">The school was very grateful for our involvement, and is looking forward to our next
                workshop – as are
                we! In fact, we would like to hold similar sessions in other nurseries (ages 3 – 5) around Paris. If you
                would like to invite us to hold one at your school – please <a href="mailto:asso.actin@gmail.com">e-mail
                    us!</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container mt-5 reveal" id="books">
    <h1 class="text-center mb-3 display-3">Books</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <p>We have been working very hard on publishing some of our stories, and are delighted to announce that the
                first three – part of the Jeunesse Esprits Curieux collection – will be published in November 2018!
                These books are aimed at children aged 3+, and have been written by members of our group – working
                scientists who are specialists in their field and want to help children (and adults) become excited
                about science. For each book, the author and illustrator have worked hard to make the story both
                scientifically accurate, as well as exciting and beautiful.
            </p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <p>
            </p>
            <img src="images/Book_example_paint_s.jpg" alt="Kitten painters" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="flex-container mt-5 reveal" id="exhibitions">
    <h1 class="text-center mb-3 display-3">Exhibitions</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <img src="images/Exhibition_s.jpg" alt="Poster" class="img-fluid" width="500">
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 reveal">
            <p>To complement the books we are publishing, and to celebrate the beautiful artwork each book contains, we
                are planning an exhibition ‘Le Jardin de Curiosites’. This will take place over the summer of 2019
                in the Jardin Curie at the Institut Curie. Please <a href="mailto:asso.actin@gmail.com">e-mail us</a> if
                you would like to find out more, or follow us on social media
                to keep updated!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer bg-dark">
    <div class="text-center">
        <a href="//www.facebook.com/Actine.SciArt/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="//twitter.com/ActineSciart" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="//www.instagram.com/actine.sciart/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@3.3.2/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem? It'll help to see the problem and try to fix it.

Comment: Try https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

Since scrolling isn't playing nice with `<div class="flex-container reveal">` consider wrapping your flex-containers in an additional `<div>` and placing the id on that outer div

```
<div id="about">  
  <div class="flex-container mt-5 reveal">
```